# Subfloor rot fix?

Tags: wood

I'm starting a complete master bath remodel and have gutted everything.  I have a small spot (about 4" x 6") where the sub floor has rotted due to water damage from a shower.  The sub floor is 3/4" thick so there is a lot of wood still under the rot area.   **My question is**, I'm about to tile over it and I want to fix the wood rot area first, what's best to do this? Considering that I'll be putting down thinset mortar.   Was thinking of patching and sanding with something like durham's water putty??   Or should I use something else??   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely NOT water putty. It'll crumble and turn to dust under the tile. Would much rather see you use thinset mortar, if you aren't going to repair it with wood/cement board. Put some mesh in the mortar, if you have any available. Any kind of mesh, or old window screen.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace it, the wood section. cutting between joists as needed to give you a new, and secure mounting point to nail to.

I'm taking this approach because while it is likely you have solved the water source issue, the damage is there already. The Plywood is already compromised. You are spending time and money to lay a new floor.  Plywood is only "so thick" because of individual layered sheets glued together. While the sheets may be intact below the visible damage, they also may not be. Also, the wood may be intact on lower sheets, but the glue may not. If the plywood is compromised, you can have creaks and squeaks or at the least, some soft area.

Test it out, and make a judgement call before deciding to leave the damaged board in place.

Comment: Really really good points.  I think replacing that little piece is best.  Thank you